# Переопределить навигатор ваадин

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

Добрый день всем,

Я только что переопределил Ваадин навигатор :

```
public class MyNavigator extends Navigator {

final SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

public MyNavigator(UI ui, SingleComponentContainer container, SpringViewProvider viewProvider) {
    super(ui, container);
    this.viewProvider = viewProvider;
    addProvider(this.viewProvider);
}

@Override
public void navigateTo(String navigationState) {
    if(ViewTokens.AVAILABLE_TOKENS.contains(navigationState)) {
        if(viewProvider.getView(navigationState) == null) {
            String uriFragment = parseViewToken();
            if(uriFragment.equals(navigationState)) {
                super.navigateTo(ViewTokens.HOME);
            }
        } else {
            //if nothing found, redirect
            super.navigateTo(ViewTokens.HOME);
        }
    }
}

private String parseViewToken() {
   <ommitted>
}
```

Как я его использую:

```
@SpringUI(path="/")
@Theme(ValoTheme.THEME_NAME)
public class MyFancyUI extends UI {

@Autowired
SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    MyNavigator navigator = new MyNavigator(UI.getCurrent(), this, viewProvider);
    setNavigator(navigator);
    navigator.navigateTo(ViewTokens.SIGNIN);
}
```

Моя попытка перейти на другой вид:

```
@UIScope
@SpringView(name=ViewTokens.HOME)
public class SplashScreen extends VerticalLayout implements View {
private ComponentHelper componentHelper;
private Button toLoginPage;

public SplashScreen() {
    initComponents();
    buildSplashView();
}

protected void initComponents() {
    componentHelper = ComponentHelper.getInstance();
    toLoginPage = componentHelper.createFriendlyButton("To Login Page",220, 60);
    toLoginPage.addClickListener(this::redirect);
}

private void buildSplashView() {
    addComponent(toLoginPage);
    setComponentAlignment(toLoginPage, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    setHeight(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
}

public void redirect(Button.ClickEvent event) {
    getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(ViewTokens.SIGNIN);
}

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent viewChangeEvent){

} 
}
```

К сожалению, кнопка перехода не срабатывает.

Из моих небольших изучений - метод getUI().getNavigator возвращает Navigator.

Как правельней решить проблему?

Comment: Настройки Security верны, что показывает дебагер?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема частично решена переопределением ViewChangeListener и использованием простого Navigator по умолчанию.

Пример:

```
Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
navigator.addProvider(viewProvider);
navigator.addViewChangeListener(new ViewChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean beforeViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {
            if(ViewTokens.AVAILABLE_TOKENS.contains(
                    UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().getState())) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void afterViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        }
    });
```